# adding url to the hyperlink field in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a dynamic grid view. I add column in page load.

I use this code for add Hyperlinkfield :

```
 string[] url = new string[1];
 url[0] = field.InternalName;
 HyperLinkField link = new HyperLinkField();
 link.HeaderText = field.Title;
 link.DataNavigateUrlFields = url;
 link.DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "{0}";
 link.DataTextField = field.InternalName;
 link.SortExpression = field.InternalName;
 grid.Columns.Add(link);
```

my problem is : for example my url is "http://Test1.docx, http://Test1.docx".

I want navigateurl set "http://Test1.docx" .

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only need `link.DataNavigateUrlFields = url.Split(',')[0].Trim();` or have I understood the question wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly what the issue is. The `field.InternalName` field contains "http://Test1.docx, http://Test1.docx" to which you are assigning to a string array and you are trying to attempt to only get the first value before the comma.

In that case, you will need to split the string:

```
string[] urlSplit = field.InternalName.Split(',');  
link.DataNavigateUrlFields = urlSplit[0];
```

Comment: DataNavigateUrlFields  get string[] .I use this code ..string[] str = field.InternalName.Split(','); link.DataNavigateUrlFields =str;link.DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}"; ... but don't work.

Comment: Try: string[] str = field.InternalName.Split(','); link.DataNavigateUrlFields = str[0];

Comment: field.InternalName is a column name of datasource , so str[0]=field.InternalName

Comment: No. Just str[0] is getting the first URL before the comma from "field.InternalName". Does field.InternalName contain "http://Test1.docx, http://Test1.docx"? If it does, then you just need to try the code from my previous comment or you may need to go into clearer detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: DataNavigateUrlFields  get string[] , when i use your code , i get error.

Comment: Cannot convert String to String[]